# Get first-level categories in liferay 7

Tags: categories, liferay-7

I am facing a problem in getting the categories in Liferay 7,
I am using the ADT to get categories of specific vocabulary as following :

```
<#if entries?has_content>
 <#list entries as entry>
  <#assign categories = entry.getCategories()>
  <#list categories as category>
    <a>${category.getName()}</a>
  </#list>
 </#list>
</#if>
```

entry type is  : AssetVocabulary

my problem is : I am getting the whole categories and sub categories of the vocabulary

for example I have this categories :

- fruits ( apples - banana )
- vegetables
- meat

so in the results I am getting all categories and sub categories as :

- fruits
- apples
- banana
- vegetables
- meat

but what i need is :

- fruits
- vegetables
- meat

I hope that I can find help here , thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
Check if the category has any parent.
if doesn't have any then display it otherwise ignore.
#set($assetUtil =  $serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.portlet.asset.service.AssetCategoryLocalService"))
#foreach ($category in $assetUtil.getCategories())
        #if($category.parentCategoryId==0)
           #set( $temp  = $category.getName())
           <div class="span10"><a href="link goes here">$temp</a></div>
        #end
#end
```